# OKTA Sso python

Tags: python, python-3.x, okta, okta-api

Hi I want to access an application that is behind OKTA sso. I am using python requests module for accessing the application. Before Okta I was able to access the application with userid and password from my python script. But after okta the script is failing to access the application.

what modification I need in my Python script using requests module

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, there is a big chance you want to access an application using Okta issued token.

You need to reach out to the application developers to identify how to properly retrieve a token. There are lots of ways to authenticate using Okta and without more information it's gonna be hard to help you out.

Once you have all those information you should be able to use any python module providing requests authentication classes for the authentication flow that you have to use.

Disclaimer: I wrote [requests-auth](https://pypi.org/project/requests-auth/) providing Okta authentication classes that can be used with requests (nominated in the Okta developer community award).

Comment: Would your package allow one to access okta protected endpoints such as in this [example][1] where the OP wanted to access a jira endopoint  using an SSWS token(jira_url = “https://jira.official.org/rest/api/2/issue/GPS-14432”) which was protected by okta.

  [1]: https://devforum.okta.com/t/how-to-login-to-okta-and-access-an-app-using-python-for-automation-purpose/11171

Comment: If one type of flow is missing, feel free to request it, but I think you are looking for this type of auth? https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-oauth-for-okta-serviceapp/-/get-access-token/